# ShowMessage is appearing behind form-Delphi

Tags: delphi

My program has got a MessageBox in the code. the first time I ran it it appeared it wasn't showing up and the program froze. I have spent hours reading through forums and I have tried everything. I minimized my form just before the MessageBox and it appears the dialogue appears behind the form. I tried this piece of code but nothing worked.

`Application.NormalizeTopMosts;                                                                            MessageBox(Handle,'Test','A message test',MB_SYSTEMMODAL or MB_SETFOREGROUND or MB_TOPMOST or MB_ICONHAND);`

P.S.: I have another form in the program and it works fine on that form and I have ensured they both have the same settings

Edit:

I just realized that it was the OnCellDraw feature of my StringGrid that caused the message to be hidden. I managed to get it to work by making the StringGrid invisible and then visible again. The OnDrawCell has the foolowing code which displays booked days of the year using cells coloured in. **I would like to know if there is a better way to make the message appear without making the stringgrid invisible. Without running the OnDrawCell, the MessageBox also works**

````
procedure TfrmClient.stgYearPlanDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  k, iMonth, iDay, iStart, iEnd, iSubtract : Integer;
begin
    case iYear of
      2020 :  begin
                iStart := 1;
                iEnd:= 12;
                iSubtract := 0;
              end;
      2021  : begin
                iStart := 13;
                iEnd:= 24;
                iSubtract := 12;
              end;
      2022  : begin
                iStart := 25;
                iEnd := 36;
                iSubtract := 24;
              end;
    end;
    for k := 1 to 31 do
      stgYearPlan.Cells[k,0] := IntToStr(k);

    for k := 1 to 12 do
      stgYearPlan.Cells[0,k] := ShortMonthNames[k];

    for iMonth := iStart to iEnd do
    begin
    for iDay := 1 to 31 do
     begin
          if ar2Booking[iDay,iMonth] = 'Y' then
          begin
            if (ACol = iDay) and (ARow = (iMonth-iSubtract)) then
            begin
              stgYearPlan.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
              stgYearPlan.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
              stgYearPlan.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left,Rect.Top,stgYearPlan.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
            end;
          end;

          if ar2Booking[iDay,iMonth] = 'D' then
          begin
            if (ACol = iDay) and (ARow = (iMonth-iSubtract)) then
            begin
              stgYearPlan.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSilver;
              stgYearPlan.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
              stgYearPlan.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left+2,Rect.Top+2,stgYearPlan.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
            end;
          end;
     end;
     end;
end;```
````

Comment: You say that you use the `ShowMessage` function, but your code is using the `MessageBox` function. Which is it?

Comment: Anyhow, you shouldn't be needing any tricks at all. `ShowMessage('Hello, World!')` should work perfectly, as should `MessageBox(Handle, 'Hello, World!', 'My App', MB_ICONINFORMATION)`. Something is wrong with your app. Try to display a msg box in a new VCL app, to see that it works. Then remove one part at a time from your app until the problem disappears.

Comment: The most likely cause, I'd say (but I'm only guessing), is that your form has `FormStyle = fsStayOnTop`, you are using `MessageBox` (and not `ShowMessage`), and you are providing the wrong window handle (the first argument must be the handle of the form). Try removing `fsStayOnTop` from the form, using `ShowMessage` instead of `MessageBox`, or providing the correct handle (you can be explicit: `Form1.Handle`).

Comment: Sorry, I used both ShowMessage and MessageBox. I wanted to use ShowMessage but i tried both to try to get it to work @Andreas Rejibrand

Comment: I'm sure we can explain this once we see the [mcve]

Comment: The problem is that *you populate the string grid with data in its `OnDrawCell` handler*. You are only supposed to draw on the canvas in this method; you shouldn't touch the data. When the grid needs to repaint, this method is called. You draw in the grid (OK), but you also change the data. Because of this, the grid realises that it needs to redraw itself again (because its data has changed!), so this method is called. You draw in the grid (OK), but you also change the data. Because of this, the grid realises that it needs to redraw itself again (because its data has changed), so this...

Comment: Thanks so much, that managed to fix the error. I removed the day and month populate. Andreas Rejbrand, you are an absolute LEGEND! :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you populate the string grid with data in its `OnDrawCell` handler.

You are only supposed to draw on the canvas in this method; you shouldn't touch the data.

When the grid needs to repaint, its `OnDrawCell` handler is called. You draw in the grid (that's OK), but you also change the data. Because of this, the grid realises that it needs to redraw itself again (because its data has changed!), so its `OnDrawCell` handler is called. You draw in the grid (that's OK), but you also change the data. Because of this, the grid realises that it needs to redraw itself again (because its data has changed!), so its `OnDrawCell` handler is called, ...

Well, I'll stop there.

Clearly, this causes an infinite sequence of repaints which will make your application busy repainting the grid.

You can see this phenomenon in action rather easily. Just create a new VCL application, drop a `TStringGrid` on the main form and add

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  StringGrid1.Cells[3, 3] := Random(100).ToString;
end;
```

You'll see a constantly updating random number in the (3, 3) cell.

Being busy with painting the grid will have many consequences. For instance, in addition to the message box anomaly you discovered, you'll likely see your process maxing out a single "thread" of the CPU (if you have a quad-core HT CPU, say, you will use one thread fully, or 1/8 = 12.5% CPU).

Comment: An an aside, the message box isn't actually hidden behind the form. It simply isn't displayed on screen until you press Alt. However, it still responds to the Esc and Enter keys. Google tells me this behaviour is not unheard of, but I still don't fully understand the precise mechanism behind it. BTW, I realised this when I tried to bring up the dialog's system menu using Alt+Space. That's a common trick to access a window hidden beneath some other window. Just open the system menu, choose "Move" and use the arrow keys to bring the window into visibility.